# How exactly does spark execute query in cassandra cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am getting started with apache spark for cassandra. I have my master slave spark set up as per [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)

I have a 5 node Cassandra cluster. With datastax's java connector, I have below code from example which works fine.

In the below code we mention only spark master and contact point for one of cassandra cluster.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.10.41")
                .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
                .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra");

        conf.setAppName("Java API demo");
        conf.setMaster("local[4]");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

[image]
As per above architecture diagram from datastax, spark worker has to be co-located with cassandra node and there's 1:1 ratio.

1. What's the implication if spark worker and cassandra nodes are
   hosted on different hosts ? Is it just network latency ?
2. How does a worker know to which cassandra node to fetch data from as I don't see we configuring it anywhere ?
3. Should cassandra node to spark worker ratio be 1:1 ?